# VC-Dimension Combination of Restructions

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, computational-complexity, machine-learning

Let $F\subseteq C([0,1]^n,\mathbb{R})$ be a finite family of functions, which is non-empty.  Let $A,B$ be subseteq of $[0,1]^n$, again non-empty, and let $vc-dim(C)$ denote the
Vapnik–Chervonenkis dimension of any $C\subseteq C([0,1]^n,\mathbb{R})$.

Is there a way to compare $vc-dim(F)$ with $vc-dim(F_|A+ F|_B)$?